# Could not open file xenial-updates_multiverse_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 213.136.12.213 80]

Tags: 16.04, updates

I get following error messages when trying to update yarn on ubuntu 16.04:

```
usr@dell:~/t1$ sudo -H apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
Hit:1 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                                                   
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                  
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                  
Hit:6 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease    
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release              
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:5 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ne0sight/chrome-gnome-shell/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu xenial InRelease          
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease           
Hit:12 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                                         
Get:14 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [488 kB]                                              
Hit:15 http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr debian InRelease                                                      
Get:16 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [479 kB]             
Get:17 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en [194 kB]                       
Get:18 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [288 kB]                      
Get:19 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [186 kB]        
Get:20 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [7176 B]                    
Get:21 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages [7164 B]
Get:22 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en [2396 B]
Get:23 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [432 kB]
Get:24 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [423 kB]                    
Get:25 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en [164 kB]                   
Get:26 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [139 kB]                      
Get:27 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [169 kB]                           
Get:28 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [8080 B]                        
Get:29 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [6872 B]                      
Get:30 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse Translation-en [3580 B]                     
Get:31 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2520 B]                    
Ign:32 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                  
Ign:33 http://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/debian lsb3.2 InRelease                            
Ign:32 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons                    
Err:32 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/nl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_multiverse_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 213.136.12.213 80]
Hit:34 http://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/debian lsb3.2 Release
Fetched 102 kB in 1s (93,3 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (extra/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Packages (extra/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Packages (extra/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Translations (extra/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Translations (extra/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target DEP-11 (extra/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target DEP-11-icons (extra/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: http://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/debian/dists/lsb3.2/Release.gpg: Signature by key F8897B6F00075648E248B7EC24CBF5474CFD1E2F uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
E: Failed to fetch http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/nl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_multiverse_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 213.136.12.213 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Target Packages (extra/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Packages (extra/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Packages (extra/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Translations (extra/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Translations (extra/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target DEP-11 (extra/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target DEP-11-icons (extra/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's too late, but maybe useful to other users. I've just got a similar problem, and with some search I found this solution:

[sudo apt-get update failing - "could not open" list file due to "permission denied"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917603/sudo-apt-get-update-failing-could-not-open-list-file-due-to-permission-deni)

As it mentions, just try to remove the content of the directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
As it contains temp files generated by the system, and due to apt interrupt there may be inconsistent files in.

Comment: Not too late, @doried-abd-allah. It save my day!